# Storing key - value in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I am using sqlite3 in development and amazon rds (mysql2) in production to store various `User` records. There are some static contents like `faq`, `change log`, `terms_and_conditions`, and such small texts.

1. The content contains `html` and changes rarely.
2. Storing in `yaml` does not seem to be viable option.
3. I show all data on a single page, and will also save/update them all at once (if possible).
4. I am using `active admin` for backend. A non-technical admin is going to store/update the data. I am going to provide a `ckeditor` to update data.

I need a way to store these data. What would be the best way to store these values? I thought of the following ways:

1. Storing each piece of data as a separate column (in a single row) e.g. columns for `faq`, `change_log`, `terms and conditions`, etc.

   Drawback is that I'll have to create a separate column if admin wants to store some other value.
2. Storing each data in two columns viz `key`, `value`.

   `faq` , `change_log` , `terms_and_conditions` can be in `key` column and their respective values in `value` column.

   Drawback is that I'll need to do several update queries when I want to update all at once.
3. Storing everything in a single column as hash, using [ActiveRecord Store](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html).

   Drawback is that I may run out of range of `text` field in some db's if data exceed too much. Also, I don't think it is much flexible.

Comment: the simplest way is to have a contents table with id and page id so each page can have its contents stored in that table. similar to how wordpress stores its data

Comment: But wordpress shows content of just one page at a time. I need to show every field at one page and update all at once.

Comment: you can update several models at once in rails look here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Ultimately, its going to be several queries in sql. Also, why would I create a model for each `key` ?

Comment: I don't know I'm just saying if you want to update multiple pages at once you can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use [RailsSettings](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings) Gem. To edit those values using activeadmin you can have some attr_accessors for each of the keys you require. You have a model for storing those semi-static data
2. You can maintain a yaml file to store those data

Comment: `RailsSettings` Gem seems to be similar to `ActiveRecord::Store`. What's the advantage of using `RailsSettings` over `Store` ?

Comment: Limitations of `ActiveRecord::Store` are mentioned in your question. `RailsSettings` overcomes those issues. it stores each value in a single row in the db. You can have default value per key. You can add new keys any time. I hope you already read the `RailsSettings` doc to get the features over `ActiveRecord::Store`